# powershell -> SOAP request with additional Headers

Tags: soap, powershell-3.0

Hi i need a help with proper soap request. I tried few ways do it but no luck.

Need to generate such soap request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header><Action xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" env:mustUnderstand="true"/><MessageID xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">uuid:..............</MessageID><ReplyTo xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"><Address>http://www.w3.org/2004/08/addressing/anonymous</Address></ReplyTo><To xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" env:mustUnderstand="true">host_url</To><wsse:Security xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="true"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">$login</wsse:Username><wsse:Password xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsse:Type="http://docs.oas
is-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">$password</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
      ................
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i stucked on this getting iis internal error 500:

```
(...)
write-host "Sending SOAP Request To Server: $URL" 
        $soapWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL) 
        $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","`"MethodName`"")
        $soapWebRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=`"utf-8`";action=`"host/MethodName`""

        $soapWebRequest.Method      = "POST" 

        write-host "Initiating Send." 
        $requestStream = $soapWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
        $SOAPRequest.Save($requestStream) 
        $requestStream.Close() 

        write-host "Send Complete, Waiting For Response." 
        $resp = $soapWebRequest.GetResponse() 
        $responseStream = $resp.GetResponseStream() 
        $soapReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]($responseStream) 
        $ReturnXml = [Xml] $soapReader.ReadToEnd() 
        $responseStream.Close() 
        write-host "Response Received."
        return $ReturnXml 

}

$url = 'host.asmx'
$soap = [xml]@"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:flow="host">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      .....
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@
$ret = Execute-SOAPRequest $soap $url; $ret | Export-Clixml  "test-$(Get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-mm-ss).xml";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your headers seem odd mixing up escaped quotes you actually don't need.

Try replacing

```
 $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","`"MethodName`"")
```

by

```
 $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","MethodName")
```

as well as

```
 $soapWebRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=`"utf-8`";action=`"host/MethodName`""
```

by

```
$soapWebRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
```